# How to arbitrarily transform component render output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, transform, redux

I'm writing an electron app that can be extended not unlike how [Hyperterm](https://hyperterm.org) can be extended. I'm trying to find a system to allow some text to be arbitrarily transformed before it is rendered on screen.

So let's say I have a component Text that simply renders as a span.

```
const Text = ({text}) => <span>{text}</span>
```

But depending on what the text contains, a plugin may change how it looks. Maybe some of the plugins will:

- Replace URLs with `<a>` tags
- Bold text surrounded by `**`, a la markdown
- Colorize certain important words
- Replace `:emoji:` with an `<img>`

What options do I have to achieve this? Is this something higher-order components can help with? Or can I change the `Text` component such that it can accept some form of transformation metadata and know what HTML to render as?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` along with a parse function if it's safe and fits your use-case

```
const parseText = text => ...
const createMarkup = text => ({__html: parseText(text)})
const Text = ({text}) => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(text)} />
```

Comment: This looks worth trying. What should I watch out for RE: exploitation? The text is coming from other people so html-escaping the text before transformation seems obvious.